# First Order Differential Equation by Substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$xe^y\cdot y' - 2e^y = x^2$ Solve the equation using the proper substitution

Comment: you should tell where you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$x^{\beta} \frac{d}{dx} [x^{\alpha} e^y]$$

Try to find a value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that matches the pattern on the left hand side.

Answer (score 1):

$$xe^y\cdot y' - 2e^y = x^2$$
$$\implies x^{-2}\frac{d e^y}{dx}+(-2)x^{-3}e^y=x^{-1}$$

$$\implies d(e^yx^{-2})=x^{-1}dx$$

Can you take it from here?